# iOS 11 Single App Mode, Disable lock screen

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-configurator

I'm working on developing a kiosk app to run in single app mode on two 12.9" iPad Pros. We want the option to turn these kiosks off so I'm using the ionic-native Insomnia and Battery-Status plugins to keepAwake when it is plugged in and allowSleepAgain when it is unplugged.

The problem is, the enclosures that were selected to house the iPads completely block all of the buttons, including the home button. When the iPads are plugged back in, the screen turns on and shows the "Press Home to Open" screen. To actually hit the home button, we need to get a key and remove the iPad from the enclosure.

Is there any way, either through the standard iPad preferences, or through the Configurator/Single App Mode preferences, to bypass the lock screen and go directly into the app when it wakes up?

I know I could probably find a way to setBrightness to 0 when unplugged and to 100 when plugged back in. But, that seems less preferable to me than letting it actually go to sleep.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do that, but at least you can use the accessibility on-display button as a quick resort. But after all, I think an iPad or any of the apple products are not suitable for such tasks. They are not designed to be used this way, they are not that flexible and modifiable. I suggest you use a high-end android tablet for this if possible. Because this is not your last configuration problem and there will be more!

Comment: Thanks Arash. Unfortunately we don’t want the accessibility home button visible on-screen over the app. Looks like I’ll end up faking it with the brightness. iPads would also be about my last choice for this but the exhibit designer had already committed to them before I was consulted and, perhaps stupidly, signed onto the project.